Child thinks the term "eetee" implies an "eater"
This question of mine reminded me of a story (perhaps even a novel) in which a child is overhearing a lot of adult conversation about "eetees" (due to a first contact situation) and wonders who the "eater" is or will be (because the kid is interpreting "eetee" as "eatee" - "one who is eaten"). Probably a pretty famous author - someone like Pohl?

This is Sundiver by David Brin.

"... Aliens, Jacob! They’re bringing extraterrestrials! In their own
ships! Oh, Jake, the Vesarius is bringing home Eatees!”
It was the first time Jacob had ever heard that word. He had often
wondered if Alice was the one to coin it. At ten years of age, he
recalled, he had wondered if “eatee” implied that someone else was to
be designated “eaten.”
As he drove above the streets of Tijuana, it occurred to him that the
question still hadn’t been answered.


Of course.  Thanks!  Will accept as soon as  the timer goes off.

The eatee should be the person who is eaten, though, because the person who does the eating is the eater.

@Adamant - Small children are not renowned for their perspicacity.

But the narrator thinks that the question still has not been answered.

@Adamant Presumably that means we don't know yet if the ETs taste good.

@DanielWagner - They're nothing to phone home about...
